# Dates rolled up into months if formatted as Date

Tags: datetime, charts, format, powerbi

With a date hierarchy in Power BI, the WeekBeginning values displayed on the visual are rolled up into months if the data type is formatted as Date.
They do display correctly, but in the wrong order, when formatted as Text.

**Correct axis labels but wrong sort order due to text formatting:**

[image]

[image]

**Correct sort order but wrong level and display since it's been rolled up into Months**

[image]
[image]

How can we set the WeekBeginning hierarchy to be formatted as Dates, and thus be displayed in the correct order but still display as Weekending text and avoid the roll up into months? To put it another way, we want the x-axis labels of the first chart, with the order of the second.

Also note: This has nothing to do with being in a hierarchy. If the field is applied outside of a hierarchy it still gets rolled up into months.

**Update: Sorting by another column**

I've also tried sorting by another column, including date and various integer values but i get these nonsensical error message. Nonsensical because there is only ONE value in the sort column for the sorted value. I then tried giving it a unique integer value (similar to using date) as per second image, but same error message. So i think this message is just plain wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating the date column and use a text version on the chart, but sort it by the date version using Sort by Column under the Modeling tab.

Comment: Your columns are not matching. Why do you have `201701` and `26/12/2016` in the same row?

Comment: Based on this `WeekIndexScaled = (DimDates[Year] * 100) + WEEKNUM(DimDates[Date], 2)` where eval context is `01/01/2017` e.g. week beginning for `01/01/2017` is `26/12/2016`. The DimDates table has a 3 year span starting from `01/01/2017`

Comment: Well if the values aren't matching, it defeats the purpose of using that column to sort with. You're taking my suggestion and doing something entirely different.